# What is the best way compare strings?

Tags: python, string

If I have a database of 2000 strings, let's say 3 of them are:
"yellow"
"blue"
"red"

I need to somehow assign value to each of the items in said database and then compare them. For example if "yellow" and "blue" is compared I want Python to output that one or the other is greater. Values would obviously be assigned manually but I can't come up with a way to have comparisons results available for the program.

Right now I am thinking of coding every string as a variable and assigning it a number so if I assign:
blue = 6
red = 5
It would tell me that blue is higher than red but I am not sure if it's efficient, especially if it's around 2000 strings that would be turned into variables.

Comment: Not clear what defines the priority of the string

Comment: Strings already are comparable...

Comment: Sticking values in a priority queue would be efficient, but without some numbering system, I think you'd lose track of values you've already added

Comment: 2000 variables is not a problem for the computer, we don't need to work with only a few kilobytes of working memory anymore. It's just a lot of work to type those assignments but you said that's what you gonna do anyway. If you had the numbers already in a file, you could read them into a Python dictionary, but if you type them by hand it's no different really than just making them variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set up 2000 variables. Use a `dict`. For example:

```
>>> wordlist =  ["yellow", "blue", "red"]  
>>> mydict = dict(zip(wordlist, range(2000)))
>>> mydict
{'yellow': 0, 'blue': 1, 'red': 2}
```

How you actually construct `wordlist` depends on what your database looks like, so I can't  offer a suggestion about that. You also don't say how the values are to be arrived at. If you want the words to be in ascending alphabetical order (so `"blue" < "red" < "yellow"`) then sort them first:

```
>>> wordlist.sort()
>>> wordlist
['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
```

Retrieving a value from a `dict`, as in `myvalue=mydict["yellow"]` is *very* efficient.